# Mongodb partial number search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following query, every filter except the `chartId` of dataType `Number` is working fine. My chartId field contains data like 10000234. What I want to achieve is that when I enter 1000 or 234 it must return user with that chartId. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
const matchNames = {
  $or: [
    { 'userId.firstName': { $regex: term, $options: 'i' } },
    { 'userId.lastName': { $regex: term, $options: 'i' } },
    { 'userId.email': { $regex: term, $options: 'i' } },
    { 'userId.phoneNumber': { $regex: term, $options: 'i' } },
    { 'userId.chartId': { $regex: Number(term) } },
  ],
};

let aggregateDataQuery = [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: 'userId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'userId',
    },
  },
  { $match: { ...matchNames } }
]
```

Comment: what is the data type of `chartId` field in collection?

Comment: chartId: Number,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight way to do this,
You can use [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) operator to match the regular expression in internal fields,

- `$toString` to convert `chartId` from number to string
- `$regexMatch` to match input term it will return true / false

```
const matchNames = {
  $or: [
    { 'userId.firstName': { $regex: term, $options: 'i' } },
    { 'userId.lastName': { $regex: term, $options: 'i' } },
    { 'userId.email': { $regex: term, $options: 'i' } },
    { 'userId.phoneNumber': { $regex: term, $options: 'i' } },
    {
      '$expr': {
        '$regexMatch': {
          'input': { '$toString': { '$toLong': "$userId.chartId" } },
          'regex': term
        }
      }
    }
  ],
};
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/45CDfE64lyp)

Comment: But `userId.chartId` is not an array. it is a big number like `10000234`

Comment: the field `chartId` field is in `userId` array of object right?

Comment: No it is object like userId = {chartId: 12331231}

Comment: return nothing :(

Comment: log display following

`    {
      '$expr': {
        '$regexMatch': {
          input: { '$toString': 'clientId.chartId' },
          regex: '1000000'
        }
      }
    }
 `

Comment: perhaps `chartId` has inconsistent number type try adding `$toLong` i have updated answer.

Comment: are you sure chartId having `1000000` this number in collection?

Comment: it is still not working :( yes there are many values including null like 10000002, 10000001, 10000003

Comment: actually in your last camment log `'$toString': 'clientId.chartId'` its incorrect field name, it should be `"$userId.chartId"`, or just copy paste from answer..

Comment: yes, I know I change that when I input in code, mistakenly pasted here

Comment: okay so check other possibilities,, can you console query and post..

Comment: console logs now Failed to optimize pipeline :: caused by : Failed to parse number 'userId.chartId'

Comment: are you sure you have added `$` dollar before field name `$userId.chartId`?

Comment: dear, I think you have made the right query. I check my data. Your effort deserve more than one vote but I'm sorry that i can do the one. I dig in to it more and will update you again